# Enable download button in a Sitecore media field to Sitecore non admin users

Tags: sitecore

I have a template called Classified Image which inherited from /sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/File template. There are some items created from Classified Image template and each item contains an image in the Media field which is coming from /sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/File template.

There are some Sitecore users without adminstrator privileges(admin testers) who simply wants to download that saved image in the classified image item. But I couldn't find a way to enable only this download option
for admin tester users so I had to give access to whole item by setting template standard values security. But the problem is even for downloading they have to acquire a lock by selecting "Lock and Edit" and later release that lock so other admin tester users won't be denied the acccess for that item.

Is there a simpler way I can configure this so this admin tester users will be able to download the image without acquiring any locks.

Answer (score 1):

After navigating to the media item, have the user navigate to the Media tab and try the Download button there - this is illustrated by the screenshot below.  If that doesn't work out you could implement a custom toolbar button that uses the `Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler` to allow downloads for otherwise unprivileged users

[image: Media Download Button]

Note: This screenshot is from **Sitecore 6.4.1**